# In-app populating of UITableView with Xcode? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm brand new to Xcode and Objective-C, and fairly new to programming in general so please correct me if I have a severe misunderstanding.

Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

- Create a Table View (empty upon startup)
- Have user add and name cells via a Bar Button (pushes to a different view with a name Text Field and "Create" button I'm assuming)
- Each created cell pushes to a new Table View with similar add/naming functionality
- Then each of *those* cells push to a Text View

It seems to me that the best way to accomplish the first part is by populating a string array, then assigning those elements to the corresponding cells. That's where I get stuck.

- How do I populate a Table View with an array?
- Should I create a new secondary Table View for every cell, or just populate the same one differently depending on which parent cell is selected?
- And same question as previous for the Text Views at the end of the chain...multiple Text Views or just different text passed each time?

If you got this far, I sincerely thank you and please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Look over the UITableView class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Mrithu's answer will give you some idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you know how to create a table view.
Now you should create a NSMutableArray to save your strings.

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *stringsArray = _stringsArray;
```

so your viewDidLoad will look like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *myTableView    =   [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    myTableView.dataSource      =   self;
    myTableView.delegate        =   self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    [myTableView release];

    self.stringsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Now the table view delegates

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.stringsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tmpTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier         =   @"MainCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell               =   [tmpTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell    =   [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.stringsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Now when you click on your barbutton to add new user, you must add it to strings array and just call `[tableview reloadData];`

I didn't understand why you want a text view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks much for your reply!  Since I'm new to Xcode, I figured I'd test the waters with a Master-Detail template using Storyboard for this project. However, as I delve further into adding the functionality I'd like, using Xcode in 'easy-mode'  is starting to seem like a less than viable option. Do you have an opinion around this?

Comment: All u need is to look into a UITableView sample code. Try this one http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/

Answer (score 0):

Read from here for complete reference of uitableview [UITableView Tutorial : Introduction to iPhone TableView](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/)